# OS X keychain issues after relocating home folder

Tags: macos, permissions, keychain

I recently relocated my home folder to a storage drive, since I'm using an SSD for my main drive. Since then, I've had issues with the OS X keychains. First it was saying that the login keychain didn't exist. Clicking the reset button didn't help; the message would just pop up again later. So then I went into keychain access and used the keychain first aid tool. It says this:

> Repair started Checking keychain configuration for alex (user ID=501)
>   Home directory is /Volumes/STORAGE/Users/alex Checked login keychain
>   Permissions incorrect on ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain, should be
>   -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxrwxrwx  Permissions corrected on ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain Checked default keychain Checked
>   contents of ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain Problems successfully
>   repaired Repair completed

So now the initial messages stop popping up, and instead messages like these start appearing:

> [Name of service] wants to use the "login" keychain. 
>   Please enter the keychain password.

They come from a variety of services and pop up every 10-15 minutes. Using the keychain first aid tool gives this message:

> Verification started Checking keychain configuration for alex (user
>   ID=501) Home directory is /Volumes/STORAGE/Users/alex Checked login
>   keychain Permissions incorrect on ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain,
>   should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxrwxrwx  Checked default keychain
>   Checked contents of ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain Problems were
>   found; you should choose the Repair option to fix them Verification
>   failed

I'm running Yosemite. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide more info on how you "relocated" the home folder?